# Calculate div height and return as margin?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a script that calculates the height of a div 'id' and returns the same value as margin-top. But this doesn't do it. What's wrong?

```
<script language="text/javascript">
var height = document.getElementById('id').innerHeight;
document.getElementById('id').style.marginTop = height + 'px';
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var height = document.getElementById('mydiv').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.marginTop = height+'px';
}
</script>
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/Kstbk/)** is a live demo.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you should only manipulate the DOM after the `onload` event is fired, or for modern browsers when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired. Anyhow, `onload` will work just fine for your case.

Try:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var height = document.getElementById('id').innerHeight;
    document.getElementById('id').style.marginTop = height + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First error in your js is  `language="text/javascript"`  it must be `type="text/javascript"`. and try to use `offsetHeight` in place of `innerHeight`

```
  <script type="text/javascript"  >

        var height = document.getElementById('id').offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('id').style.marginTop = height + 'px';
        }
  </script>
```

And call it `onload` event.

thanks ,